# PageUp/PageDown issue when combobox inside a scrollviewer

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, event-handling, scroll

I have a simple requirement.

I have a Combobox inside a scrollviewer. When the combobox is open and I press PageUp or PageDown then the background is also moving if the vertical scrollbar is visible.

Is there any way to stop the PageUp/PageDown to work only on the combobox when necessary?

Below is the Xaml and code-behind.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplicationDemo.ComboInScrollViewer"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         Title="ComboInScrollViewer" Height="300" Width="300">
     <ScrollViewer>
         <Grid Height="500">
             <ComboBox x:Name="listContainer" Height="30" Width="90" />
         </Grid>
     </ScrollViewer>
 </Window>
```

**CodeBehind**

```
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplicationDemo
 {
     /// <summary>
     /// Interaction logic for ComboInScrollViewer.xaml
     /// </summary>
     public partial class ComboInScrollViewer : Window
     {
         public ComboInScrollViewer()
         {
             InitializeComponent();
             listContainer.Items.Add("1st");
             listContainer.Items.Add("2nd");
             listContainer.Items.Add("3rd");
             listContainer.Items.Add("4th");
             listContainer.Items.Add("5th");
             listContainer.Items.Add("6th");
         }
     }
 }
```

I cannot use `e.handled = true` directly, because the event is fired for the `ScrollViewer` first and then it is fired for the `Combobox`. I think I am missing something. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying for 1-2 months here is  a work around

**Xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplicationDemo.ComboInScrollViewer"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="ComboInScrollViewer" Height="300" Width="300">
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="scParent" PreviewKeyDown="ScrollViewer_PreviewKeyDown" >
        <Grid Height="500">
            <ComboBox x:Name="listContainer" Height="30" Width="90" />
            <Button Click="Button_Click" Height="30" Width="90" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,100,0,0"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtValue" Width="90" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,50,0,0"/>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Window>
```

**Code behind**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApplicationDemo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for ComboInScrollViewer.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ComboInScrollViewer : Window
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr GetActiveWindow();

        public ComboInScrollViewer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            listContainer.Items.Add("1st");
            listContainer.Items.Add("2nd");
            listContainer.Items.Add("3rd");
            listContainer.Items.Add("4th");
            listContainer.Items.Add("5th");
            listContainer.Items.Add("6th");
        }

        private void ScrollViewer_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.PageUp || e.Key == Key.Prior)
            {
                listContainer.RaiseEvent(new KeyEventArgs(InputManager.Current.PrimaryKeyboardDevice, PresentationSource.FromVisual(listContainer),
                    1, Key.Home) { RoutedEvent = Keyboard.KeyDownEvent }
                );
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            else if (e.Key == Key.PageDown || e.Key == Key.Next)
            {
                listContainer.RaiseEvent(new KeyEventArgs(InputManager.Current.PrimaryKeyboardDevice, PresentationSource.FromVisual(listContainer),
                    1, Key.End) { RoutedEvent = Keyboard.KeyDownEvent }
                );
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Handled = false;
            }
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                listContainer.RaiseEvent(new KeyEventArgs(InputManager.Current.PrimaryKeyboardDevice, PresentationSource.FromVisual(listContainer),
                    1, Key.End) { RoutedEvent = Keyboard.KeyDownEvent } 
                );
            }
            catch (Exception objExp)
            {
                // Handle Error
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Will this help you any futher?

```
  <ScrollViewer PreviewKeyDown="UIElement_OnPreviewKeyDown">
    <Grid Height="500">
      <ComboBox x:Name="listContainer" Height="30" Width="90"/>
    </Grid>
  </ScrollViewer>


private void UIElement_OnPreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.Key == Key.PageUp || e.Key == Key.PageDown) && this.listContainer.IsDropDownOpen)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Instead of e.Handled you could place some another custom logic inside.

Its just an idea :)

Comment: If I will do this, then scrollviewer will not scroll also the event will not work in the combo.

Comment: Ah ok, the scrollviewer will work, it will stop working only when ComboBox is open. You would need EventManager and to register a handler that even calls method even though its handled is set to true. I will try to find a example for this.

Comment: Thanks dev. Please let me know if you find any example.